# See if user is accessing two systems from same computer?

Tags: security, cookies, ip

So we have two systems. One we control completely, and the other less so, but we still can put some code here or there, mostly javascript/HTML however. They are on different domains. One flag of potential malicious activity is when a single machine is accessing both systems, i.e. from the same computer. Is there a somewhat reliable way (ignoring people trying to circumvent it) that I can tell if a single machine accessed both systems.

What we tried was, when a person viewed a critical page on domain.com, we used domain2.com's api to see what ip address they last used there and compared them. However, because of NAT, we get too many flags since two computers on the same network will often have the same exposed IP.

I investigated cookies, but because of browser security that doesn't seem like a viable option.

Is there a reliable method to detect something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Make site A set a cookie on load, and make site B send a request to a URL on site A that sets a different cookie.

If, in either request, the user already has the other cookie, do something.